# Export data in .xls format rather than tab delimited

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export-to-excel

HI i am exporting some data from database in .xls format but when i try to save my file it alerts me that file type is not .xls format. I need to store it in excel 97-2003 Workbook. when i pretend for save as option, default file type is in as tab delimited.. how can i overcome it?? below is my code..

```
if ( $_POST["frmDownload"] == "Excel") {
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=employee_details.xls");
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [phpExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/119187) which is excellent for all excel manipulation.

Here is the list of [examples](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples).

use the method [fromArray](http://www.codeinphp.com/general/php-libraries/create-excel-sheet-array-php-using-phpexcel/) to write excel from array which is fetched from persistent data.

use the method [toArray](http://www.codeinphp.com/general/php-libraries/convert-excel-sheet-into-php-array-using-phpexcel/) to form a php array from excel sheet.

The learning curve is very simple first try first example only from official site.
Then try the fromArray and toArray its very easy and also phpExcel have lots of functionality like gradient background for a cell, border size increasing, formula manipulation and new worksheet also easy to create.

Important: read [documentation](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/documentation) on when ever you get free time

Comment: ya thats good brother.. but is this possible to modify this routine to get what i desired??

Comment: If it solve your problem please accept the answer by clicking tick mark this may help others too. And rewriting routine is very small foot print only. Just call the `fromArray` method.

Answer (score 0):

The format is tab delimited... You are just 'naming' it excel in this way... Look at gvgvgvijayan's answer for the solution to your problem.